# Combine identical rows with adjacent business_time periods in DB2 temporal tables

Tags: sql, db2, temporal-tables

I have a temporal DB2 table with a `business_time` `PERIOD` that looks like this:

```
      id local_unit vehicle      start        end
   12389       3538   21147 2019-01-01 2019-07-01
   12389       3538   21147 2019-07-01 2019-12-31
```

I would like to modify the table and combine rows like the ones above, where all values are identical and the business_time periods are adjacent. The result should look like this:

```
      id local_unit vehicle      start        end
   12389       3538   21147 2019-01-01 2019-12-31
```

The solution must also consider that there might be periods in the data that are *not* adjacent which should not be combined. Performance is not an issue since this would be a batch job that would only run a few times a year.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? From a functionality perspective using temporal SQL there is no difference.

Comment: just for perfectionism; it irks me to have the unnecessary rows but it would require very awkward code to avoid them in my application logic. i was hoping there would be an elegant sql solution to "clean up" the tables every once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

This is a gap and islands problem.  As stated, you can use `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select id, local_unit, vehicle, min(start), max(end)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_end >= start then 0 else 1 end) over 
                 (partition by id, local_unit, vehicle order by start) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(end) over (partition by id, local_unit, vehicle order by start) as prev_end
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by id, local_unit, vehicle, grp;
```

The `lag()` finds the previous end time.  The `sum()` is counting the number of times there is *not* an overlap -- this is the beginning of an "island".  The final logic just aggregates the values.

Comment: thanks! that's a great input, however, I want to modify the existing table, not just select from it... of course I could do something hackish via a temporary table but I want to try to avoid that